# After upgrading to Debian12 and upgrading packages apt shows: The following packages have been kept back: sysv-rc-conf

Tags: debian, apt, sysv

After upgrading Debian11/KDE to Debian12, restarting and running `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get this: `The following packages have been kept back: sysv-rc-conf`. I can't install it because then it asks to remove many essential packages like plasma-workspace. What should be done?

Comment: Same problem here. Curious to find out what the solution is.

Comment: Same here. Found the corresponding Debian Bug report https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1042467 (without replies at this time)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade from Debian 11 Bullseye to Debian 12 Bookworm I experienced the same problem.

```
# apt upgrade
--- cut ---
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:   sysv-rc-conf
```

In such cases I use Aptitude command which can suggest more than one resolution of package conflict.

```
# aptitude dist-upgrade

The following packages will be upgraded: 
  sysv-rc-conf{b} 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 21,6 kB of archives. After unpacking 1 024 B will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sysv-rc-conf : Depends: sysvinit-core but it is not going to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     sysv-rc-conf [0.99-7.1 (now)]
```

I did not accepted proposed solution to keep the package.

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages: 
1)     sysv-rc-conf [0.99-7.1 (now)]
```

As Aptitude proposed new solution to remove package, I accpted it.

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurses-ui-perl{u} sysv-rc-conf{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 750 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 510305 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sysv-rc-conf (0.99-7.1) ...
Removing libcurses-ui-perl (0.9609-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
                                         
Current status: 0 (-1) upgradable.
```

No more kept back sysv-rc-conf package.

```
# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

Comment: But that does not explain why it occurred, and what the implications of removing it are, and why you think doing so would be the best solution.